# How can a list or vector in Clojure be used to store and use functions?

Tags: function, collections, clojure

Here is what I tried in the REPL.

```
(def mstuffs [(fn [n] (* 1 n)) (fn [n] (* 1 n))])
((mstuffs first) 2)
```

Here is the error I got

```
; Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate$fn$fn (interruptible_eval.clj:87).
; Key must be integer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Vectors in clojure are functions from index to to the corresponding item e.g.

```
([:foo :bar :baz] 1)
=> :bar
```

so `(mstuffs first)` is trying to index the vector `mstuffs` with the argument `first`. Since `first` is a function not an integer you get the resulting exception. It looks like you mean to invoke the first function in the vector so should use

```
((first mstuffs) 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Boy do I feel silly now. I've been staring at it too long. :)